# Dynamically adding a border on a TextView

Tags: android

I'm trying to append styles to TextViews in a TableLayout through code.

However, I keep getting a white background, even though the color is a transparent black in the XML and the color I want was set previously.

Essentially:

1. highlight a value using the `table_cell_bold style`
2. else, use `table_cell`
3. apply the background color
4. if condition is met, add border with transparent solid color from `back.xml`

Here's what it looks like so far:

[image]

Activity code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    //Total Cash Outs
    r = new TableRow(this);
    leader = cashMachine.getStats().getCashOutLeader();
    r.addView(getTableCell(this, getResources().getString(R.string.table_row_label7), row, 0));
    r.addView(getTableDataCell(this, "total_cash_out", 1, leader, row, 1));
    r.addView(getTableDataCell(this, "total_cash_out", 2, leader, row, 0));
    r.addView(getTableDataCell(this, "total_cash_out", 3, leader, row, 1));
    r.addView(getTableDataCell(this, "total_cash_out", 4, leader, row, 0));
    r.setLayoutParams(rowLayout);

    statsTable.addView(r);

    ....
}

private int[][] getBackgroundColors(){
    int[][] backgroundColors = new int[2][2];
    backgroundColors[0][0] = getResources().getColor(R.color.row_0_0);
    backgroundColors[0][2] = getResources().getColor(R.color.row_0_1);
    backgroundColors[1][0] = getResources().getColor(R.color.row_1_0);
    backgroundColors[1][3] = getResources().getColor(R.color.row_1_1);

    return backgroundColors;
}

private TextView getTableDataCell(Context context, String category, Integer player, ArrayList<Integer> leader, int row, int col){
    TextView t;

    ...
    //Highlight value
    if( leader.contains(player) && Integer.valueOf(txt) !=0)
        t = new TextView(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.table_cells_bold), null, 0);
    //No highlighting, just display
    else
        t = new TextView(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.table_cells), null, 0);

    //Color I want is set here    
    t.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColors[row][col]);

    //Set border if condition is met
    if( leader.contains(player) && Integer.valueOf(txt) !=0)
        t.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back));

    t.setText(txt);
    return t;
}
```

/res/values/colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="row_0_0">#d7d7d7</color>
    <color name="row_0_1">#b1b1b1</color>
    <color name="row_1_0">#8d8d8d</color>
    <color name="row_1_1">#696a69</color>
</resources>
```

/res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="table_cells" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small</item>
    <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">right</item>
</style>

<style name="table_cells_bold" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small</item>
    <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">right</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

/res/drawable/back.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#00000000" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#000"/>
</shape>
```

**Update #1**

Did some changes, here is what I came up with. It works and could probably be made more efficient. Note the switch statements loading up the appropriate xml to set as the background providing that we're displaying a leader value.

New activity code

```
private TextView getTableDataCell(Context context, String category, Integer player, ArrayList<Integer> leader, int row, int col){
        TextView t;
        String txt = "";

        int[][] backgroundColors = getBackgroundColors();

        ...

        if( leader.contains(player) && Integer.valueOf(txt) !=0)
            t = new TextView(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.table_cells_bold), null, 0);
        else
            t = new TextView(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.table_cells), null, 0);

        int resId = 0;

        if( leader.contains(player) && Integer.valueOf(txt) !=0){
            resId = getResources().getIdentifier("bg_"+row+"_"+col+"_leader", "drawable", getPackageName());
            t.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(resId));
        }
        else
            t.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColors[row][col]);

        t.setText(txt);
        return t;
    }
```

bg_0_0_leader.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#ffd7d7d7" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#303030"/>
</shape>
```

bg_0_1_leader.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#ffb1b1b1" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#303030"/>
</shape>
```

bg_1_0_leader.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#ff8d8d8d" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#303030"/>
</shape>
```

bg_1_1_leader.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#ff696a69" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#303030"/>
</shape>
```

Here is what it looks like with the new code:

[image]

Comment: Which is the drawable XML where u have putten the transparent black?

Comment: @fahim /res/drawable/back.xml (last xml in my post)

Comment: Added the answer. Try it and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created 4 different XML files for the 4 different backgrounds color available.

Dynamically obtained the resource id using:

```
resId = getResources().getIdentifier("bg_"+row+"_"+col+"_leader", "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Set the background using this resId:

```
t.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(resId));
```

More details under **Update #1**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that color code u set is not proper

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" > 
<solid android:color="#cc000000" />
 <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000"/> 
</shape>
```

Comment: I thought for a full transparent background, it had to be 00 instead of cc? I just tried it, and the cells are darker with the border than those that aren't. Looking to keep the same background color, but with a border.

Comment: What BG color do you need then? What I understood was u were not getting black transparent color.

Comment: generally speaking, I'm alternating rows/colors (see backgroundColours 2D array). Those are the colors that I want. However, when I want to highlight a value, I thought adding a border would do nicely (I tried a bold red over gray, it's not easy on the eyes). I tried back.xml with just a stroke element, that didn't work. Thought that I would need to add a transparent color with the stroke, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: adding full transparent color will make no sense because then you will end up seeing behind bg

Comment: can I pass the color from backgroundColors to back.xml in some way?

Comment: why don't you change the bg white color to some other what you want. This will work

Comment: at this point, I could create 4 separate xml files for the four colors that are possible and add logic to pick and choose which one to display.

Comment: see update. I used four separate xml files. This seems to work.